# Attaching keyboard events to an SVG Element inside HTML

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

Is there anyway to attach a textInput or keypress (or indeed any other text input) event to an SVG Element when running SVG inside HTML in a browser?

I can attach an eventhandler to document.documentElement but nothing happens when I attach an eventhandler via whatever mechanism to an SVGElement of anykind ... SVG, g, rect...

I see from the SVG spec that this is not supported ([W3 SVG list of events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#SVGEvents)), but do any Browsers support any 'extras'?

I cannot get the following to work on Chrome or Firefox...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Key event test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f00;
}

#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: #0f0;
    float: right;
}

#drawArea {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#side {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background: #00f;
    float: left;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function createBoundEventHandler(el, name) {
        var f = 
            function eventHandler(ev) {
    if("mousedown" === ev.type) {
        el.focus();
    }
    else {
        alert("asEventHandler: " + el.localName + " " + name + " " + ev.type);
    }
    return true;
            };
        return f;
    }

    function doEvent(event, elementName, eventName) {
        alert("asAttribute: " + elementName + " " + eventName + " " + event.type);
        return true;
    }

    function addEventHandler(element, eventName, type) {
        var attrName = "on" + eventName;
        var attrValue = "doEvent(evt, '" + element.localName + "', '" + eventName + "')";
        if("asAttribute" === type) {
            element.setAttribute( attrName, attrValue);
        }
        else {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, createBoundEventHandler(element, eventName), false);
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() { 
        var eventHandlerType = "asEventHandler"; //asAttribute asEventHandler

        var svgTarget = document.getElementById('drawArea');
        var svgRect = document.getElementById('aRect');
        var nonSVG = document.getElementById('side');

        addEventHandler(svgTarget, "keypress", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgTarget, "mousedown", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgTarget, "keyup", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgTarget, "keydown", eventHandlerType);

        addEventHandler(svgRect, "keypress", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgRect, "mousedown", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgRect, "keyup", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(svgRect, "keydown", eventHandlerType);

        addEventHandler(nonSVG, "keypress", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(nonSVG, "mousedown", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(nonSVG, "keyup", eventHandlerType);
        addEventHandler(nonSVG, "keydown", eventHandlerType);

        //We can get a keypress if we attach an event handler to the underlying document Element    
        addEventHandler(document.documentElement, "keypress", eventHandlerType);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="side" tabindex="0">
    </div>
<div id="main">
    <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="drawArea" focusable="true" tabindex="0"> 
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
            style="fill:yellow; ;stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" id="aRect" focusable="true"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As the example shows I can still fallback on key events on the 'background' doc element. Does anyone have any pet libraries, techniques for relating this back to an SVGElement.

N.B. I have also tried tabindex(0) and focus to no effect...

Comment: Works under IE9 because IE9 seems to implement the  focusable="true" attribute on the rect. ( Drawing a dotted line around it )

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747848/attaching-keyboard-events-to-an-svg-element-inside-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple answer might be that the ['focusable'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/interact.html#focusable-attr) attribute isn't supported in those browsers. For key event listeners on e.g a `<rect>` to make any sense there needs to be a concept of focus inside the svg.

Comment: It would certainly seem so. I tried to indicate to the browsers that I wanted the SVG Tiny 1.2 approach ( xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny"), but this created more problems than it solved. Who/where should I go to get a definitive answer - that its not supported - and I have to roll my own?...  I'll try it with Opera...

Comment: The 'version' and 'baseProfile' attributes are ignored by all browsers AFAIK, but they can probably cause trouble in authoring tools such as Illustrator if it tries to ensure that the file conforms to some particular profile.

Comment: If you use XHTML instead it will work as you expect in Opera I think, or you can try the HTML5 Ragnarök builds - http://labs.opera.com/news/2011/02/22/.

Answer (score 5):

As user Erik Dahlström suggested, you (first) need to add an event listener for focus.

```
svgRect.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    this.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    });
}, svgRect);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tudormi's code works fine, but be careful of memmoryleaks, because everytime you focus svgRect, new keypress event will be registered on that element.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).  Also, I've had a lot of success using [MooTools](http://mootools.net/).  I'm sure you could probably add some event handlers with any JavaScript framework, if you didn't want to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is ***Key*** events, not attaching events per-se. I don't think Moo or Raphael help directly with this. I'm using backbone.js for other events and it works fine for them, I wrote the example to be framework agnostic.